# How to get an interactive geographic map for a country?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, svg

I want a map where the regions are with hovering and clickable just like [this one](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/maps/GalleryMap.asp?mapName=Pakistan) but in this case for Pakistan and its regions. I did not find any online interactive map for Pakistan and I've searched for SVG and HTML and HTML5 and CSS maps, there seems to be none avilable. Do you have an idea for how I should go about getting a map like I want?
[image]

### Update

> Hello, I want to activate an interactive map for Pakistan. I've
>   previously done it with Jquery an other libraries (SVG) for India
>   (www.koolbusiness.com) and for USA (www.hipheap.com) and for Brazil
>   (www.montao.com.br) and now I want to do it for Pakistan. I see you
>   have a pretty good map here that I want to replicate:
>
> http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/maps/GalleryMap.asp?mapName=Pakistan
>
> Getting that functionality would do what I need, could you guide what
>   I need to do / buy? I've downloaded the example
>   FuctionMaps_XT_Trial.zip and I suppose I must buy it to activate the
>   Pakistani map. In the future we will also want to get more maps but we
>   are starting with Pakistan and evaluating your map library.
>
> Thanks /Nick Rosencrantz
>
> 2013/7/16 FusionCharts Team  This message
>   serves as confirmation that you are now successfully registered in our
>   support center.
>
> Registered Email: nik...@gmail.com Password:
>
> You can visit the Support Desk at any time by going to
>   http://support.fusioncharts.com/
>
> Please do let us know if you have any questions.
>
> Regards,
>
> FusionCharts Team
>   ------------------------------------------------------ Support Center: http://support.fusioncharts.com/index.php?
>
> --

Comment: For which country do you want it?

Comment: @screenmutt Pakistan. I'm looking at the FusionMaps_XT if it can do it. I have a budget.

Comment: Well, they say that you should use solutions in this order: free, money, time.

Comment: There are also easy ways to do it yourself ... if you have an image and you want to make it clickable (make an html image map) you can even use some online tools like [this one](http://www.image-maps.com/).

Comment: Is your problem finding the data, or writing the javascript code to do hover/click/highlight? For data: www.gadm.org For JS maps: openlayers or leaflet.js

Comment: This question is definitely a bit of a mess - but I'm not sure if finding data and a way to apply code to it is really off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for "pakistan wikipedia regions" has the following results:

- [Federally Administered Tribal Areas in Pakistan (claims hatched).svg](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aFederally_Administered_Tribal_Areas_in_Pakistan_%28claims_hatched%29.svg) (SVG)
- [small PNG](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aSub_Pakistan.png)
- [clickable map and 1 SVG per region below](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_units_of_Pakistan#Structure_of_administrative_units)

License of Wikipedia (and wikimedia Commons) content should be [CC-BY-SA](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use#7._Licensing_of_Content) afaik

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just right-click > View Source and download all the appropriate files. Use Chrome and you'll get everything you need. Line up your directories the way you need them and render it.

Here's the link for Pakistan [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/maps/GalleryMapAll.asp?mapName=Pakistan).

Comment: I'll try again but I think it is a properietary .swf that only loads if it is loaded from their server. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Because, say, the license forbids it except if OP buy one?

Comment: Check this one out, too... I think this one is nicer and it does everything you want it to... Click [here](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)